# split linearlayout width between wrap_content and the rest

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout, horizontal, and with variable width (width is set to fill parent) containing two textboxs A and B.

I need : 
textbox B (the black one) takes as much width as it needs (wrap_content ?)
textbox A takes what's left.

Pictures to illustrate :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.35"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="asd" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is perfect, can you explain why this is working ? when you use weight, don't you have to put weight for the two boxes?

Comment: you can if you want to stabilize them. But if you don't set weight to the second one, you are saying that it's changing and you need to wrap_content. But for the first one, take the rest of the space as its weight covers all the leftover space

Comment: you can also do `android:layout_weight="1"` instead of 1.35 :)

Answer (score 0):

use relativelayout instead.like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <!-- black box -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <!-- white box -->
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

NOTE: i see in some device,because of language direction or device setting, linearlayout change children position. for example black text box come to left and white text box goes to right,but if use relativlayout it never happen.